# How to sort text files, in Python, in rows

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

I would like to know how to sort numbers in ascending order when outputting a text file in Python.

At the moment I can sort the names of my text file alphabetically; and I could sort my numbers in ascending order, however I want to keep the scores corresponding to the student in the same row.

```
import operator
class1 = open('sample.txt','r') 
sort = sorted(class1,key=operator.itemgetter(0))
for eachline in sort:
    print(eachline)
```

This is the code so far and the output is this:

```
Holy = 10 ,6 ,10 

Jhnn = 9 ,0 ,1 

Oli = 5 ,7 ,6
```

But how would you sort the numbers so it would look like this:

```
Holy = 6 ,10 ,10 

Jhnn = 0 ,1 ,9 

Oli = 5 ,6 ,7
```

Comment: well, you are printing a line of text, so first thing would be to see if elements are integers and then sort them

Comment: reading I mean sorry

Comment: thanks for the help, i will try that

Comment: You could also reverse the data structure. Put the last element in the first position and the first position in the last.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for eachline in sort:
    line = map(int, eachline.split(","))
    sorted_line = sorted(line)
    print(" ,".join(map(str, sorted_line)))
```

We can split on the comma and map that to a list of integers. We then sort that list and join it back to a comma-separated string of integers.